# API PHP - Filter item - by created_on

Tags: php, podio

I am trying to filter my items by hour in a day but can't get expected result.

I only want the last two hours of a day and I am doing it by cron job for every 2 hours.

My code :

```
$attributes = array();
$attributes['sort_by'] = 'titre';
$attributes['sort_desc'] = true;
$attributes['filters'] = array("created_on" =>array("from" => "2016-08-09 13:00:00","to" => "2016-08-09 15:00:00"));
$attributes['limit'] = 10;
$attributes['offset'] = 0;
$attributes['remember'] = false; 
PodioItem::filter($myappid, $attributes, array());
```

This example should give me only one result, but it fails and gives me all items of the 2016-08-09 day. Is it possible to filter by date/time  ?

Sorry for my English level

Thanks for reading my problem

Comment: Show some of the programming you already made.

Comment: Ok i put some code.
That's working but like i said not exactly as i wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe what you are asking for is currently not possible with the API. I just checked our item filter handling, and we effectively flatten `created_on` filters to use "whole day" granularity. This means that even if you provide a higher-precision range of timestamps, anything beyond the date will be ignored.

So, in your example:

`"from" => "2016-08-09 13:00:00", "to" => "2016-08-09 15:00:00"`

Those parameters are altered within the API backend to look like:

`"from" => "2016-08-09 00:00:00", "to" => "2016-08-09 23:59:59"`